# Apache Flink - org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have created an application with Apache FLink 1.0.3 using Scala 2.11.7 and I want to test it locally (a single jvm). So I did the following as stated in the website:

```
./bin/start-local.sh
tail log/flink-*-jobmanager-*.log
```

And it starts just fine, I can see the web interface at localhost:8081.
Then, I tried to submit my application, but I get either an exception or a weird message. For example when I type either of the following commands:

```
./bin/flink run ./myApp.jar
./bin/flink run ./myApp.jar -c MyMain
./bin/flink run ./myApp.jar -c myMain.class
./bin/flink run ./myApp.jar -c myMain.scala
./bin/flink run ./myApp.jar -c my.package.myMain
./bin/flink run ./myApp.jar -c my.package.myMain.class
./bin/flink run ./myApp.jar -c my.package.myMain.scala
```

I get the following exception:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Neither a 'Main-Class', nor a 'program-class' entry was found in the jar file.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.getEntryPointClassNameFromJar(PackagedProgram.java:571)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.<init>(PackagedProgram.java:188)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.<init>(PackagedProgram.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.buildProgram(CliFrontend.java:922)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:301)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1192)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1243)
```

And when I type either of the following commands:

```
./bin/flink run ./ -c myMain myApp.jar
./bin/flink run ./ -c myMain.class myApp.jar
./bin/flink run ./ -c myMain.scala myApp.jar
./bin/flink run ./ -c my.package.myMain myApp.jar
./bin/flink run ./ -c my.package.myMain.class myApp.jar
./bin/flink run ./ -c my.package.myMain.scala myApp.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
JAR file is not a file: .

Use the help option (-h or --help) to get help on the command.
```

The above commands do not work either with -c or --class. I use IntelliJ and I compiled the application using the Build Module from Dependencies option. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that `myApp.jar` does not contain the `MyMain` class? Could you maybe run `jar -tf myApp.jar` and verify that it contains the above-mentioned class and that this class contains a `main` method?

Comment: I used the command you mentioned and for a weird reason I couldnt find any of the classes I created. Why is that happening?

Comment: I used WinRar to open the jar and see its contents and I could locate every class of my project and I could locate MyMain.class and MyMain$.class

Comment: Maybe that's the problem that the `jar` command cannot list the contents properly. This could indicate that you jar file is somehow corrupted.

Comment: Sorry, for my incorrect previous comment. I could finally locate my main class with the command you provided. I am quite sure that the jar file is not corrupted.

Answer (score 15):

The correct way to submit your JAR is:

```
bin/flink run -c my.package.myMain myApp.jar
```

You have to specify the arguments (like `-c`) before the JAR file. You got the error messages initially, because `./` was interpreted as the JAR and the rest of the line was ignored.

The `-p` argument is optional. Your last example works, because the argument order is correct and not because of the parallelism flag.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was wrong. Flink needed to pass the parallelism degree as an argument, otherwise there was a program invocation exception. The command below worked for me:

```
./bin/flink run -p2 --class myMain myApp.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the entry point class in your pom file.
see the following part in the pom file snippety

```html
<transformers>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
<mainClass>com.xyz.myMain</mainClass>
</transformer>
</transformers>
```

Please check the below snippet.